# Getting memory leaks from Appcelerator Alloy app

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have an Alloy app. It has got 7 windows and opens at same time. When user close a opened window `$.removeListener(); $.destroy();` codes runs at window close event. But I am getting memory leaks on Android device. %90 windows has got ListView, every window has got max 2 Listview. What is the right approach for multiple windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why you would want to open 7 windows at same time when user can only see max 1 window at a time.

It's dead simple, open only that window which user should see first, & create a link-flow to other window in previous window.

Can you think of any app on Play Store which does so, if you have, then please send me its link, I would really love to review it?

But if you mean to say that user will see all windows at same time in a scrolling behaviour or like paging, then go to **Ti.UI.TabGroup**

Comment: Think about ajax browser navigating. How can I do this with appcelerator.

Comment: I have one physical file for window. When user pass params to that window content is changing. Additional to this file I have 4 physical files more.

Comment: This is a style that you can use, as @Prashant Saini mentioned in another comment above. Each alloy controller could use <View> as its base instead of <Window> and then you add and remove the base view as you see fit etc.

Comment: @Prashant Saini thank your for your suggest. I created 2 array in alloy.js for link-flow. One array is for windows other one is windows args. When user wants to open new window current window is closing. When user wants to go back windows which is closed opens again with using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that your event listeners are being removed?

I don't know the function `$.removeListener();` is this a custom function?

As a general rule I try and put as many of my event listeners into the xml, as these are automatically removed, and have a custom function `destroyMe()` that runs onClose which removes any other listeners that I may have used and `$.destroy()`

Ti.App.addEventListener is a killer too, make sure these are removed if you use them!

ps: i totally understand the 7 windows bit :-)

Comment: can you hint me why he needs to open 7 windows at same time?

Comment: e.g. Using a NavigationWindow on iOS that is 7 windows deep. Android doesn't have this component and so the alternative is to open new windows for each step and keep them open behind. I could be totally mis-understanding the app though :-)

Comment: But why do you need to keep them open behind? for what? NavigationWindow is just a box which organises your windows, but still it shows single window at a time. As user of this question says, it opens 7 windows at same time, this is what I am trying to understand. :D

Comment: @Prashant Saini  and Martyn Joyce thank you for your interest. Every window has got own params and they opens by user navigating. I can't close parent window because of it's dynamic params. Dou have any idea?

Comment: @Kerberos, can you provide us a visual hint of what you want because it's getting really tough for me to understands your needs? :)

Comment: And I have one physical file for window. When user pass params to that window content is changing. Additonal to this file I have 4  physical files more.

Comment: $.removeListener(); is not a custom function http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller-method-removeListener

Comment: @Kerberos interesting, thanks for pointing out that one has passed me by. I would confirm that it is correctly removing any event listeners that you have added as these are still likely to be the root of your issue i think.

Comment: From what you describe you could just change the content in the window instead of opening another one. If they even have the same elements you could just change their content (or hide them and show another one). It would be even quicker instead of opening/closing many windows. That would be more "ajax" like. Also try opening one window and look at the memory when closing it. Easier to find the leak instead of looking at 7 at the same time

Comment: @miga thank you. So what is the best approach open new and close parent window?

Comment: Open it with `open()` put all the views/listview inside this window, hide/show things you want to present and at the end close the window with `close()`. Or put a `ScrollableView` inside the window, put all the 7 sub-windows into it and switch to each slide. Depending on your usecase